# How to print items in an object array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am returning an object from a site which apart from other parameters also contains an array of objects.

If I do console.log(req.body.cart) I print this [ { title: 'iphone 6', cost: '650' } ]

which I need only the title. I tried stringify, which is not what I want and parse which returned an 500 error.

```
router.post('/itemstobuy', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.name || !req.body.lastname || !req.body.address
      || !req.body.email || !req.body.cart){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

   var mailOptions={
    from: 'anEmail@gmail.com',
    to: 'anotherEmail@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Subject',
    html: '<p>Name: ' + req.body.name + '</p>' +
    '<p>LastName: ' + req.body.lastname + '</p>' +
    '<p>Address: ' + req.body.address + '</p>' +
    '<p>Email: ' + req.body.email + '</p>' +
    '<p>Cart: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body.cart) + '</p>'
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
  });

  return res.status(200);
});
```

I need to show the items by their title at

```
'<p>Cart: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body.cart) + '</p>'
```

The above works but there are lots of ugly data and need just the titles of the items.

Comment: `'<p>Cart: ' + req.body.cart.map(function(item){ return item.title; }).join(', ') + '</p>' `

Comment: @noppa you were right. I could have never see that solution. Add an answer below so I can select it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments:

```
'<p>Cart: ' + 
 (req.body.cart || []) //Just to make things not crash and burn if we have no cart
     //Take the title from each of the items
     .map(function(item){ return item.title; })
     //Create a comma-separated string from the titles
     .join(', ') + 
'</p>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `'<p>Cart: ' + JSON.parse(req.body.cart).title + '</p>'`

Answer (score 0):

In case you have multiple items in the cart you can iterate through these otherwise you can access it directly `req.body.cart[0].title`

```
var cart = req.body.cart;

var html: '<p>Name: ' + req.body.name + '</p>' +
'<p>LastName: ' + req.body.lastname + '</p>' +
'<p>Address: ' + req.body.address + '</p>' +
'<p>Email: ' + req.body.email + '</p>';

 html +=  '<p>Cart:<ul> '+

for(var i=0;i<cart.length;i++) html +='<li> ' + cart[i].title + '</li>';

html +='</ul></p>';
```

```js
 var cart = [ { title: 'iphone 6', cost: '650' }, { title: 'iphone 5', cost: '550' } ];

  document.write( '<p>Cart:<ul> ');

for(var i=0;i<cart.length;i++) document.write('<li> ' + cart[i].title + '</li>');

document.write('</ul></p>');
```